# Change application from Oracle to Hadoop

Tags: java, sql, ajax, oracle, hadoop

I currently have a web application that runs with all of the data in Oracle.  At the high level, the application consists of a java applet, some java servlets, some Ajax, and the oracle database.  I was wondering what converting the whole suite to Hadoop instead would cost in terms of work?  Below are some questions that can help me get a grasp on it.

Is there any software that can take SQL database schema creation scripts and queries and convert them to appropriate calls in Hadoop?

How different are the Java APIs for communicating with Hadoop to that of oracle SQL?

Theres a bit of Ajax in there too, how different is that from SQL to Hadoop?

Please consider me a beginner when explaining anything having to do with Hadoop.  I don't need to drill down into specifics (unless you want to), just high level talks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hadoop is not suitable for usecases which needs real time querying and processing. Hadoop is best when used for offline batch processing and data analysis. You can refer to following link - [Common Questions](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/05/5-common-questions-about-hadoop/) for getting some of you questions answered. You dont have a schema concept in HDFS, which is the filesystem in Hadoop. Data is stored in blocks on disk as a regular file.

I would suggest you visit [apache hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)  to learn what is hadoop and in which use case it fits best.

Comment: Ah ok, as you can see, i have no experience with Hadoop.  So essentially, I should have asked the question with the word "HBase" instead of "Hadoop"?

Comment: I would suggest that you read this blog - [link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/04/hbase-dos-and-donts/) and see if HBase is a good fit in your usecase. The move from RDBMS to NoSQL totally depends on the use case. If you are worried about constrains and transaction management the stick with Oracle or any other RDBMS. NoSQL is best when you need flexibility in the data model structure, where each record may not have same set of attributes.

Comment: So, I actually need aspects of both of them (Hadoop + RDBMS), but the processing I've been doing with some other software.  I was hoping to transition the database now, and then later on use the same system for the analytics.  Thanks for the links!  Probably should have done more research before posting!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for SQL on Hadoop solution that is performant, then check out InfiniDB.
http://infinidb.co

We are a 4th generation columnar MPP engine behind MySQL.  We can sit on top of HDFS, GlusterFS or on your local system, so we can be on Hadoop or not, your choice.  We are fully open source, GPLv2, there is no difference between the open source version and the enterprise version, use it as you want, scale as you need.

We operate in the interactive SQL area, many people use us for analytical queries against their data.  Hadoop MapReduce is great at batch work and transformations, but falls short on the interactive side of things, and that is where solutions like InfiniDB come in.

While you are on Oracle and using Oracle SQL, there may not be much difference between that and the MySQL syntax we support, depends on all the features of Oracle you are using.  Many people use us a drop in replacement with their existing MySQL database to start to get the performance of having a cluster MPP database.  Also transitioning to Hadoop as you mentioned is another use case, as we can provide the SQL interface for your applications to not even realize they are working on top of a Hadoop cluster.

Feel free to contact me if you have any questions / comments.